# How to fix problems with querystring in show_more tag?

Tags: python, html, django, pagination

I use pagination on scroll of [django-el-pagination](https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination) application in my own project.

```
django==django==1.11.5
django-el-pagination==3.1.0
```

When user scroll to the last page in terminal I notice next Traceback. It seems to me that something wrong with `querystring` which in `show_more` tag. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?!

**P.S.** As I said this Traceback happens only when user scroll to the last page. Lets say I have 5 page, so this Traceback happens only when user at last page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/documents/?page=5&querystring_key=page
```

**ERROR:**

```
Time: [25/Jan/2018 08:37:38] | LevelName: DEBUG | Module: base | Process: 1148 | Thread: 123145435922432 | Message: Exception while resolving variable 'querystring' in template 'documents/documents.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [querystring] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function _get_val at 0x109034ed8>>}]
```

**views.py:**

```
from el_pagination.views import AjaxListView

class DocumentListView(AjaxListView):
    context_object_name = 'documents'
    template_name = "documents/main.html"
    page_template = 'documents/documents.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        documents = Document.objects.all()
        return documents
```

**documents/main.html:**

```
<div class="list-group">
    {% include page_template %}
</div>
```

**documents/documents.html:**

```
{% load el_pagination_tags %}

{% paginate 20 documents %}
{% for document in documents %}
    {% include "documents/list_template.html" %}
{% endfor %}
{% show_more %}
```

**documents/list_template.html:**

```
<div class="list-group-item">{{document.title}}</div>
```

Here is link to template which use `show_more` tag: [show_more.html](https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination/blob/develop/el_pagination/templates/el_pagination/show_more.html)